# Formating date using XSLT to first day of calendar year

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to format a date using an xslt style sheet in order to return the first day of the current year. I am also trying to do this for an  to return the last day of the current year. Here is the current version of XML and schema I am using :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

The code I am currently using to retrieve the dates:

```
<StartDate>
   <xsl:value-of select="../Start_Date"/>    
</StartDate>

<EndDate>
   <xsl:value-of select="../End_Date"/>  
</EndDate>
```

Comment: What XSLT processor you are using?

Comment: With XSLT questions, ALWAYS say which version of XSLT you are using. Date and time functionality is available in XSLT 2.0 and later, but many users are still stuck on version 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can output the date of the first day of the current year using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(), '[Y]-01-01')" />
```

or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:value-of select="year-from-date(current-date())"/> 
<xsl:text/>-01-01<xsl:text/>
```

Similarly, the date of the last day of the current year can be produced using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(), '[Y]-12-31')" />
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="year-from-date(current-date())"/> 
<xsl:text/>-12-31<xsl:text/>
```

Comment: Just wondering if there is a way to do this on versions lower than  version 2.0 in case this comes up again?

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 you need to use a processor that supports an extension function for getting the current date, or pass the current date as a parameter at runtime. Once you have the current date, you can extract the year using `substring ($current-date, 1, 4)` and proceed from there.